# Partial sum involving $S_n$-character values.

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be partitions of $n$ and let
$\chi^\mu_\lambda$ denote the character value of irreducible representation $V_\mu$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ evaluated
over the conjugacy class $C(\lambda) \subset S_n$. Furthermore let $\displaystyle z(\lambda) := {n! \over {|C(\lambda)|}}$ where
$|C(\lambda)|$ is the size of the conjugacy class.

**Question:** Given a third partition $\eta$ with $|\eta| = n + 1$ what is the combinatorial/representation theoretic meaning of the following "partial" sum ?

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\stackrel{\scriptstyle \text{all $\lambda$}}{\eta \, = \, \lambda \, + \, \Box}} \, \chi^\mu_\lambda \, z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda)
\end{equation}

p.s. By "partial" I mean that the sum is **not** taken over **all** partitions $\lambda \vdash n$. The value of the sum in that case would be either 1 or 0 depending on whether or not $\mu = 1^n$
owing to the first orthogonality relations for the symmetric group.

p.p.s. Clearly this quantity can be viewed as the value of the $S_n$-fourier transform $\widehat{\delta_S}(\mu)$ where $\delta_S$is the characteristic function supported on the union $S$ of the conjugacy classes $C(\lambda)$ with $\eta = \lambda + \Box$. Beyond this surface observation, can anything more be said (for instance, by way of the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule) ?

p.p.p.s. The context that I have in mind is the following:
Given any function $f:\Bbb{Y} \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}$
on the Young lattice $\Bbb{Y}$ define
its *Young-Fourier* transform $\hat{f}$
as the function $\hat{f}: \Bbb{Y} \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}$ given by

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(\mu):= \sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \, f(\lambda) \, \chi^\mu_\lambda \, z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda)
\end{equation}

Let's also define the Young-Laplace operator $\Delta$ by

\begin{equation}
\Delta f(\lambda) := \ f(\lambda) \, - \, 
\sum_{\eta = \lambda + \Box} \, f(\eta)
\end{equation}

where $f: \Bbb{Y} \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}$ is any function. Basically $\Delta$ is the so called "up-operator" known in the study of differential posets.
I'm interested in a kind of *symbol* of the Laplace operator, i.e. in calculating the Young-Fourier transform $\widehat{\Delta}$ of the Laplacian, where $\widehat{\Delta}f := \ \widehat{\Delta f}$. Indeed

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \widehat{\Delta}f(\mu) &= \, \widehat{\Delta f}(\mu) \\ \\
& \displaystyle = \, 
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \, (\Delta f)(\lambda) \, \chi^\mu_\lambda \, z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda) \\ \\
& \displaystyle = \, \sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \, 
\Big(f(\lambda) \, - \, 
\sum_{\eta = \lambda + \Box} \, f(\eta) \Big)\, \chi^\mu_\lambda
\, z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda) \\ \\
& \displaystyle = \, \hat{f}(\mu) \, - \, 
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \sum_{\eta = \lambda + \Box} \,
f(\eta) \, \chi^\mu_\lambda 
\, z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda) \\ \\
& \displaystyle = \, \hat{f}(\mu) \, - \, 
\sum_{\eta \, \vdash \, n+1} f(\eta) \, 
\sum_{\stackrel{\scriptstyle \text{all $\lambda$}}{\eta = \lambda + \Box}} \, \chi^\mu_\lambda \, z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

As the reader can see, the partial sum addressed in question of this post
is relevant to the calculation. Beyond this I would like to know what is the commutator
of $\Delta$ and $\widehat{\Delta}$.

p.p.p.p.s. I invite the readers to edit the title of the question if there is a more appropriate wording that reflects the intended meaning.

regard, Ines.

Comment: Normally when you see addition or removal of a box from a partition you should think of induction and restriction of representations. In this case for example, the partial sum over all $\lambda$ formed from removing a box of $\nu$ of $\sum \chi^\mu_\lambda$ is the character (evaluated at cycle type $\mu$) of the $S_{|\nu|}$-irrep $\nu$ restricted to $S_{|\nu| - 1}$.

Comment: Sure, good point. Nevertheless there is the $z^{-1}(\lambda)$ factor which gets in the way.

Comment: The $z$-factor is part of the inner product on characters isn't it? (Or perhaps the inner product on the columns of the character table)? It's hard to say more without seeing a context where it's used.

Comment: Yes, I would say it is part of the inner product; basically it's a rewriting of a sum taken over the entire symmetric group in the case where the function is a conjugacy-invariant. More explicitly: ${1 \over {n!}} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \, u(\sigma) \overline{v}(\sigma) = \sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \, u(\lambda) \overline{v}(\lambda) z^{\scriptscriptstyle \, -1}(\lambda)$ for a pair of class functions $u, v: S_n \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}$.